# Interaction between a categorical and a quadratic continuous variable

Tags: interaction, quadratic-form

I have three main hypotheses:

1. Independent variable $X_1$, which is a categorical variable of two levels (A and B), may have an effect on the response $Y$.
2. Independent variable $X_2$, a continuous variable, may have an effect on the response $Y$.
3. The effect of $X_1$ over $Y$ is smaller in lower and upper values of $X_2$, but higher in central values of $X_2$. It is like a quadratic response of $X_2$ over the effect of $X_1$ in $Y$.

Is it possible to express it in a single linear model? Something like:

```
lm(Y ~ X1 * (X2 + I(X2^2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by making $X_1$ a dummy variable (=0 for category `A` and 1 for category `B`). The most general version is

$$
\begin{split}
\mu  = & \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_2 + \beta_2 X_2^2 +  \\
       & \beta_3 X_1 + \beta_4 X_1 X_2 + \beta_5 X_1 X_2^2
\end{split}
$$
or equivalently we can say that the intercept, slope, and quadratic term differ between group `A` ($\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$) and group `B` ($\beta_0+\beta_3$, $\beta_1+\beta_4$, $\beta_2 + \beta_5$).  The expected difference between `A` and `B` (the "effect of treatment `B`") is exactly $\beta_3 + \beta_4 X_2 + \beta_5 X_2^2$, so if $\beta_5<0$ your statement (effect of `X_1` is small for low $X$ and high $X$ and largest for intermediate values) is reasonable.

This general quadratic model can be expressed as `~X1*(1+X2+I(X2^2)` or `~X1*poly(X2,2)` in R's (Wilkinson-Rogers) formula language.

One thing to be careful of is that for sufficiently large or small $X_2$ and large (negative) $\beta_5$, $X_1$ could have a strong effect **in the opposite direction**, so "smallest effect for intermediate values" is somewhat dependent on the context (by "smallest effect" do you implicitly mean a positive effect?) and range (how far can $X_2$ extend towards low and high values)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And yes, my idea of "smallest effect" is a small positive or negative effect. In that case, if the effect of X1 is strong negative in small values of X2, strong positive in intermediate values of X2, and small positive in large values of X2, X2 would still have a strong quadratic effect on the effect of X1, am I right?

Comment: yes ...........